# Pure c++ app for Android and its performance

Tags: android, c++, performance

Can I write a pure C++ app for Android? (for example, using NDK?)

Considering there's no difference of functionality, is pure Android C++ app faster and consumes lesser memory than Android Java app? In just my guess, I guess it is YES because C++ app won't do garbage collection which causes frame rate hiccup.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes and yes, althrough Google says:

*"Using native code does not result in an automatic performance increase, but always increases application complexity... If you write native code, your applications are still packaged into an .apk file and they still run inside of a virtual machine on the device. The fundamental Android application model does not change."*

from http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

(Personally, I don't agree that writing in C++ automatically makes a more complex program than Java, I'd even say it's the other way around for a skilled C++ programmer)

Comment: Just to add on this, with `android.app.NativeActivity` there's even a built in and reusable activity you can use as a wrapper for your C/C++ code (so you don't even have to fiddle around with Java stuff to get your app running).

Comment: Theoretically, yes, but practically you will need to fiddle with Java or JNI as the parts of the Android Library you can access from NDK is very limited. Google could of course hire one competent programmer to wrap more of the Android library to be accessible from the NDK, but they seem to not care at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons to do it.

One would be to finally be safe from constantly being forced to encounter new brokenness as you were forced to "upgrade' from one broken toolchain to the next when you almost have the brokenness under control.

Answer (score -2):

Well, no you can not do pure c++ on android devices.

There is no reason for it. you are still running in the same virtual machine as your java code. So unless you need to squiz these tiny bits of performance you would go for writing your CPU consuming procedures in c++ and invoke them via Java code.

It sounds like you are making a game, well then just use OpenGL ES with java, and offload heavy computing in to compute shaders.