# Good beginners material about writing android app purely in c++ (not hybrid java/c++ apps)

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, qt-creator

I install qt-creator and I would like to write android apps purely in c++ (not using java code at all). I know, that it's possible to do it. I created new project, which haven't got any java files and it's worked.. I mean hello world is showed on emulator screen :D This [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977454/pure-c-app-for-android-and-its-performance) says it as well

and my question is do you know any good materials about writing android apps in c++. 
I searched and only thing I can find is how to prepare Qt-creator to work with android, few books and bunch of materials about writing app in c++ with elements written in java by using NDK.  I can't find any books/good tutorial which would describe on newbie level or any level, how to write apps only in c++, not using java at all.

Comment: If you're more specific about what kind of apps you want to write, you *might* get someone to give you some kind of answer.

Comment: android apps isn't enough information? For me it means that I want to write apps which would be work on device with android system.

Comment: I mean, do you want to write GUI applications? Games? Network server/client applications? Just saying "I want to make an Android app" is like saying "I want to make a Windows program", it's very broad.

Comment: GUI and Network server/client application. I would work mostly with these types of app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to use the Andrid NDK and C++:

1. Either write your application in Java/Xml using the Android SDK and use JNI to access the APIs implemented in C/C++ using the Android NDK.
2. Write a native activity in C/C++, which allows you to implement the lifecycle callbacks in native code.

There are tools such as AIDE or Eclipse which support both. AndroidStudio doesn't support NDK yet.

The extra way is to use [Qt5](https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/07/23/anatomy-of-a-qt-5-for-android-application/) to produce rich QML/C++ apps for Android.

About the question, it was previously discussed on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899740/android-ndk-tutorial-guide-for-beginners) already.